# Has something like "Knuth's Up-Arrow Factorial Notation" ever been used? If so, what practical uses does it have?

Tags: factorial, tetration, big-numbers

I was studying Knuth's up-arrow notation and I was wondering if ever something like "Knuth's up-arrow factorial notation" has ever been used. Now I know this probably isn't a recognizable term, because I made it up. My question is basically asking if something like that(possibly with a different name) has ever been used to create enormous numbers. I'll explain how it works:

Knuth's up-arrow notation works like this:

You have *a*↑*b* which results to *a*<sup>*b*</sup> or *a* * *a* * *a* ..... * *a* where the amount of *a*'s are equal to *b*.

For example:
 4↑3 would be 4<sup>3</sup> or 4 * 4 * 4 or 64.

Using double arrows is where the numbers start getting big. *a*↑↑*b* is equal to *a*<sup>*a*<sup>*a*<sup>.<sup>.<sup>*a*</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup> where the amount of *a*'s is equal to b.

For example: 4↑↑3 would be equal to 4<sup>4<sup>4</sup></sup> or 4<sup>256</sup>. That's a big number!

Enough explaining that. What I like to call "Knuth's up-arrow factorial notation" is where we use arrow notation but *b* is changed to *b* factorial.

For example: You have a↑<sub>!</sub>b which results to a<sup>b!</sup> or  a * a * a ..... * a where the amount of *a*'s are equal to *b*!.

So, 4↑<sub>!</sub>3 would be 4<sup>3!</sup> or 4<sup>6</sup> or 4096. Double arrows get even crazier. 4↑↑<sub>!</sub>3 would be equal to 4<sup>4<sup>4<sup><sup>4<sup>4<sup>4</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup> which is an enormous number! To simplify that without using scientific notation would be 4<sup>4<sup>4<sup>4294967296</sup></sup></sup>. Basically it's just like Knuth's up-arrow notation but with the *b* variable put to a factorial.

So what I'm asking is if something like that has ever been used before or if it's something that could be put to practical use.

Comment: These numbers are special cases of extremely large numbers, but I would write your example $4\uparrow\uparrow 6$ just as $4\uparrow\uparrow 3!$. I do not think that the symbol "$\uparrow\uparrow !$" usually is used to write up such numbers. Practical uses will such big numbers not have, a number like $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 3$ is just too big to have any physical meaning. And even the much smaller number $4\uparrow\uparrow 4$ is probably too big for practical purposes.

Comment: I mean this in the most respectful way: I don't see a benefit to moving the exclamation point to the arrows. $4\uparrow\uparrow\, 5!$ seems fine.

Comment: I was just wondering because numbers like Graham's number use the up-arrow notation and so we could use those steps and add the factorial to explode to an even larger number. Just a thought.

Comment: @Eth189, note that $n!<n^n=n\uparrow\uparrow 2$ so that if your goal is to make larger numbers, you're much better off using another $\uparrow $ than a $!$ (no matter where you'd prefer to place it).

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks for the clarification. The point of the **!** is to make the _b_ factorial. Thus _n_ to the power of _n!_ > _n_ to the power of _n_.

Comment: @Eth189, I think we're talking past eachother a bit. I understand your proposed notation. I just assumed from "explode to an even larger number" that your goal is to make big numbers (with compact notation). If so, then, for example, $3\uparrow \uparrow \uparrow 5$ is far larger than $3\uparrow \uparrow \,5!$. Taking a factorial of the second argument isn't as dramatic as adding another arrow.

Comment: Consider the Ackermann function. It can be defined in closed form by the Knuth notation.

Comment: @Wuestenfux But the Ackermann has practical uses, mainly an introduction on basic recursion, as it is simpler than Knuth's notation IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, such "factorials" are not named, and as far as constructing large numbers go, they are quite small. It appears as though all you've done is

$$a\uparrow^k!b=a\uparrow^k(b!)$$

which is a seriously pointless thing. I doubt on an practical use, even for the sake of making large numbers, since

$$a\uparrow^{k+1}b\gg a\uparrow^k(b!)$$

That is, your factorials don't add anything onto the strength of Knuth's up-arrow notation.

And on top of that, what's the point of making a *new* notation when we can already write it easily?

Answer (score 0):

No.
Just No.
The only way it could have any application to anything is if only one arrow is used, but that is the same thing as exponentiation.
Even with double arrows, the numbers would have to be small to have any meaning.
For example, 2^^2 is equal to 4, and 3^^3 is equal to around 7.6 trillion.
4^^4 would be so large already that it would make absolutely no sense in reality.
The number of Planck volumes in the entire observable universe is only around 10^186.
4^^4= 4^4^256= 4^(around 10^153) 
Meaning that 4^^4 comes close to a googleplex.
Which is 10^10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

So, the only number using Knuth's Up-Arrow Notation that has any meaning or practical use is 3^^3.
For example, A light year has a similar amount of kilometers.